# Form the equation of lowest degree with rational coefficients which has........?

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

Form the equation of the lowest degree with rational coefficients which has $2+\sqrt{3}$ and $3+\sqrt{2}$ as two of its roots

I tried taking $x=2+\sqrt{3}$, $3+\sqrt{2}$ and also $y=\sqrt{3}$, $y=\sqrt{2}$ but got no results. The equation becomes too complicated and the degree of $x$ becomes too much (greater than $4$).

The answer is $x^4-10^3+32x^2-34x+7$

Comment: Hint:$$(x-(2+\sqrt{3}))(x-(2-\sqrt{3}))(x-(3+\sqrt{2}))(x-(3-\sqrt{2}))=\dots$$

Comment: Oh thanks. I've got it.^_^